# When I changed format of date, the sorting broke in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I was creating table which contains data being date and what I wanted to achieve is to first convert default date format into "MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm:ss". All is ok the date format is displayed successfully but the sorting of data in table  started working improperly. If I change date format into DD-MM-YYYY then sorting works perfectly but not working properly with "MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm:ss". So, I have this code:

```
response => {
       const withFormattedDate = [...response.data].map(_item => {
         return {
           projectCreatedDate: 
            moment(_item.projectCreatedDate).format("MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm:ss")};
        });
```

and

```
<tbody>
  <tr
    ng-repeat="project in model.pagination.viewPage"
    ng-class="{'administration__inactive-project' : !project.activeNow}"
            >
      <td>
        <span>
          {{project.formattedDate}}
        </span>
      </td>
    /tr>
```

The question is how to make sorting work even if I use `'MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm:ss'` format?

Comment: Where is the code you used to sort?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort by transforming the date to milliseconds format, like `yourTime.getTime()`. And compare it to each other.